# How to calculate the degree of agreement by row comparisons in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, match, row

For a minimal, reproducible example (reprex) let's assume I have a database object (dbo) in a Microsoft SQL Server and I want to query things in T-SQL.

My dbo looks like this:

```
Animal-ID   Marker-ID   Allele1     Allele2
--------------------------------------------
1           OAR1        A           G
1           OAR2        C           C
1           OAR3        T           G
2           OAR1        A           C
2           OAR2        C           C
2           OAR3        A           C
```

What I would like to do is calculate an allele match percentage per Marker-ID across all Animal-IDs.

Given the dbo example from above the desired result looks like this:

```
Animal-ID-pair  Marker-ID   Match-percentage
--------------------------------------------
1-2             OAR1        50
1-2             OAR2        100
1-2             OAR3        0
```

So far, I tried the following approaches:

First I thought selecting individual rows is sufficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Animal-ID ASC) AS rownumber,
         Animal-ID, Marker-ID,
         Allele1, Allele2
     FROM 
         dbo) AS foo
WHERE 
    rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

and then compare that to the range between 4 and 6.

The problem here is that, in my real and way lager data set, not all animal-ID pairs have the same number of rows, i.e. not the same number of markers.

That is why I thought grouping might be helpful:

```
SELECT 
    Animal-ID, Marker-ID,
    Allele1, Allele2
FROM 
    dbo
WHERE 
    Animal-ID IN (SELECT Animal-ID FROM dbo
                  GROUP BY Animal-ID 
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

but that does not allow me to do comparisons and/or calculations across groups.

Thus I would like to ask how to calculate the degree of agreement in the comparison of row pairs.

Comment: `Allele1 and Allele2 are dynamic columns or static..?`

Comment: What would the expected result be for extra sample data `Animal-ID=3` with only 2 records `OAR1` and `OAR2`? Do you want a result row for `Animal-ID-pair=1-3` and `OAR3` with `Match-percentage=0` or no row at all?

Comment: @Mansoor They are static columns. Background information if intereseted: The values of the columns are results of bio lab experiments. Thus the values are added once and then they are fix and do not change.

Comment: @Sander Actually no row at all would be preferred, but having a row which says 0 is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
create table genomes
(
  AnimalId int,
  MarkerId nvarchar(10),
  Allele1 nvarchar(1),
  Allele2 nvarchar(2)
)

insert into genomes (AnimalId, MarkerId, Allele1, Allele2) values
(1, 'OAR1', 'A', 'G'),
(1, 'OAR2', 'C', 'C'),
(1, 'OAR3', 'T', 'G'),
(2, 'OAR1', 'A', 'C'),
(2, 'OAR2', 'C', 'C'),
(2, 'OAR3', 'A', 'C'),
(3, 'OAR1', 'A', 'G'), --new sample Animal with less data (no OAR3)
(3, 'OAR2', 'C', 'G');
```

**Solution**

1. Select all unique animals `cte_AllAnimals`.
2. Select all unique markers `cte_AllMarkers`.
3. Combine every animal with every animal behind it `a2.AnimalId > a1.AnimalId`. This will give you all unique animal combinations.
4. Combine every pair with every marker `cross join cte_AllMarkers`.

This gives me:

```
with cte_AllMarkers as
(
  select g.MarkerId
  from genomes g
  group by g.MarkerId
),
cte_AllAnimals as
(
  select g.AnimalId
  from genomes g
  group by g.AnimalId
)
select convert(nvarchar(10), a1.AnimalId) + '-' +
       convert(nvarchar(10), a2.AnimalId) as AnimalIdPair,
       m.MarkerId,
       case g1.Allele1 when g2.Allele1 then 50 else 0 end +
       case g1.Allele2 when g2.Allele2 then 50 else 0 end as MatchPercentage
from cte_AllAnimals a1
join cte_AllAnimals a2
  on a2.AnimalId > a1.AnimalId
cross join cte_AllMarkers m
left join genomes g1
  on  g1.AnimalId = a1.AnimalId
  and g1.MarkerId = m.MarkerId
left join genomes g2
  on  g2.AnimalId = a2.AnimalId
  and g2.MarkerId = m.MarkerId
order by a1.AnimalId,
         a2.AnimalId,
         m.MarkerId;
```

**Result**

```
AnimalIdPair MarkerId MatchPercentage
------------ -------- ---------------
1-2          OAR1     50
1-2          OAR2     100
1-2          OAR3     0
1-3          OAR1     100
1-3          OAR2     50
1-3          OAR3     0
2-3          OAR1     50
2-3          OAR2     50
2-3          OAR3     0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41cc05db342f07ca754da66bbd8e632e) to see it in action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! All the given answers worked conceptually, but yours .) is the most understandable one for an SQL-learner, .) is the easiest to edit and modify (for example adding things like SELECT "TOP 1000" in order not to use the whole dbo) .) and it also turned out to be the most performant solution. My actual real dbo has 427 million rows and applying your approach yielded the fastest results (on a SQL server machine with 130 GB RAM and 16 CPUs).

Answer (score 1):

By Using **SUBQUERY** & **STUFF**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Animal_ID  INT, Marker_ID CHAR(10)  , Allele1 CHAR,    Allele2 CHAR)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,'OAR1','A','G'),
(1,'OAR2','C','C'),
(1,'OAR3','T','G'),
(2,'OAR1','A','C'),
(2,'OAR2','C','C'),
(2,'OAR3','A','C')

SELECT * FROM  @T 

SELECT S.*,(ISNULL(S1.C,0)+ISNULL(S2.C,0))*100/LEN(Allele_Pair) AS Percentage
FROM (
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CONCAT('-' , Animal_ID ) FROM @T t1
WHERE t1.Marker_ID = t2.Marker_ID FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Animal_ID_Pair 
,Marker_ID,
STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(Allele1,Allele2) FROM @T t1
WHERE t1.Marker_ID = t2.Marker_ID FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') AS Allele_Pair
FROM @T t2
GROUP BY Marker_ID) S
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Marker_ID,Allele2,COUNT(Allele2) AS C FROm @T GROUP BY Allele2,Marker_ID HAVING COUNT(Allele2)>1) S1 ON S1.Marker_ID=S.Marker_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Marker_ID,Allele1,COUNT(Allele1) AS C FROm @T GROUP BY Allele1,Marker_ID HAVING COUNT(Allele1)>1) S2 ON S2.Marker_ID=S.Marker_ID
```

Output:

```
Animal_ID_Pair  Marker_ID   Allele_Pair Percentage
1-2               OAR1          AGAC    50
1-2               OAR2          CCCC    100
1-2               OAR3          TGAC    0
```

Answer (score 1):

A self-join does what you want -- with some arithmetic:

```
select t1.animal_id, t2.animal_id,
       ( case when t1.allele1 = t2.allele1 then 1.0 else 0 end +
         case when t1.allele2 = t2.allele2 then 1.0 else 0 end +
       ) / 2.0 as match_percentage 
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.marker_id = t2.marker_id and
        t1.animal_id < t2.animal_id;
```

Although it is easy enough to add new alleles into this.  You can also express this as by unpivoting the alleles and aggregating:

```
with ta as (
      select t.*,, v.*
      from t cross apply
           (values (1, allele1), (2, allele2)) v(allele, val)
     )
select ta1.animal_id, ta2.animal_id, mta1.marker,
       avg(case when ta1.val = ta2.val then 1.0 else 0 end) as match_percentage
from ta ta1 join
     ta ta2
     on ta1.marker_id = ta2.marker_id and
        ta1.animal_id < ta2.animal_id
group by ta1.animal_id, ta2.animal_id;
```